# MongoDB (via Fuelphp): Adding entries on an Array

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, fuelphp

I would appreciate the help here. For the purpose of this discussion I have an example here (I will use paste bin for the codes):

http://pastebin.com/VPuyKn6W

I am trying to produce this output:

http://pastebin.com/4iMLacRu

I understand that I need to use $push to make this work. But upon testing, it doesn't seem to do anything. I am following the instructions as prescribed in the [docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/mongo/methods.html#/get_collection), but instead of using $Id, I am using user_id for finding the document in the collection. Here is my model:

http://pastebin.com/QB94tbZn

Am I misunderstanding something, or I am not using the $push operator properly, or something to do on how I created the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After walking outside, I finally got my answer.

```
    public static function create_mongo()
{
    $data = array(
        'user_id'       => '123895',
        'First_Name'    => 'John',
        'Last_name'     => 'Doe',
        'sites'      => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Sankaku Complex',
                'site'  => 'http://sankakucomples.com'
            )
        )
    );

    $db = Fuel\Core\Mongo_Db::instance();
    $db->insert('test_collection',$data);
}
```

sites should be an array carrying an array variable.

Comment: $push is for updating an existing array value.  You're inserting a new record (which uses $set, behind the scenes).